# Interpretation of probability current density of hydrogen atom wave function

Tags: quantum-mechanics, probability, quantum-interpretations, hydrogen

I'm trying to understand the physical interpretation of the value of the probability current density of an electron in a hydrogen atom: $$j_r=0$$$$j_{\theta}=0$$ $$j_{\phi}=\frac{h}{rsin\theta}|\psi_{nlm}(r,\theta,\phi)|$$
I kind of understand why $j_r=0$, but I can't find any physical interpretation for $j_\theta$ being 0 and $j_\phi$ being non-zero and positive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $j_{\theta}$ were non-zero, then the probability would bunch up at one pole, and leave the other. (I know, there is no pole on a hydrogen atom, but when you pick a coordinate system and get in a $L_z$ eigenstate, there kind of is.)

The azimuth angle, $\phi$, is the only coordinate that circles around atom, so there can be a nonzero current in a stationary state.

It's the same in parabolic coordinates (in which the hydrogen atom is separable).